# What will happen when autorelease object is assigned to strong variable

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, autorelease

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is AutoRelease redundant when using ARC in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752790/is-autorelease-redundant-when-using-arc-in-objective-c)

I am new to objective C and understanding its memory management . I was really stuck understanding the behavior of strong variables. Below is snippet which really confuses me. I have following method and I am using ARC.

```
-(void) watchStrongVariable {
    MyClass * myobj = [self getMyClassObject];
    // ...
}

-(MyClass *) getMyclassObject{
    return [[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

In line #2 , I am assigning `MyClass` object to a local variable `myobj` . I read that all local variables are by default strong and strong is similar to retain. So in the above case my assumption is `myobj` is retained and is owned in method `watchStrongVariable` but here comes the question as `myobj` is retained should we not release `myobj` explicitly by calling `[myobj release]` .I saw many of the programs which follows the same pattern but there is no release message sent to local variable . Can someone explain me as to why release of `myobj` is not required in the above case.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use retain, release or **autorelease** when you're using ARC, because ARC will take care of that for you. You can simply do this:

```
- (MyClass *)getMyclassObject {
    return [[MyClass alloc] init];
}
```

The compiler will add the autorelease call for you. But the whole point of ARC is not having to think a lot about this anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You will not need to **autorelease** anything when using ARC. In fact, this will generate a compiler error.

So this would be correct when using ARC:

```
-(MyClass *) getMyclassObject{
    return [[MyClass alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: "In fact, this will generate a compiler warning." Rather an error - warnings are not fatal, but this one is. +1 though.

Comment: Thanks H2CO3, you are right. I revised my answer.

Answer (score 2):

One, you can't use explicit `retain`, `release` nor `autorelease` when under ARC - the compiler won't permit it.

Two, you don't have to think about this at all in this case as it's a simple one - when a strong variable goes out of scope, it's equivalent to a `release` message. So how all this works under ARC is:

```
- (void)watchStrongVariable
{
    MyClass *myobj = [self myClassObject]; // implicit retain-on-assignment
    // implicit release-on-end-of-scope
}

- (MyClass *)myClassObject
{
    return [[MyClass alloc] init]]; // implicit release-after-return
}
```

Some advice about coding style. One, don't use `getXXXX` for getter names - that's reserved for methods which have output artuments (i. e. which accept pointers to be written to), like UIColor's `getRed:green:blue:alpha:` method.
Two, for functions, the opening brace goes on a separate line, and the asterisk indicating pointer types shall be collided with the variable name and not the type. So the best is to write `int *i;` and not `int* i;` nor `int * i;`.

Comment: thanks for all your replies . I will take all the suggestions into consideration . If in the above case I am not using ARC what will be the impact and is release on myobj is necessary and why.